# How to increment checkbox id after append - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a default one checkbox and the other checkboxes will appear after I click an add button. I need to check whether a checkbox is checked or not. But the problem here is my jquery only works on the default checkbox only. The code are as follow:

**HTML:**

```
<form_answer>
<input type="hidden" class ="" id="correct_hidden" name="correct_hidden[][correct]" value="0"/>           
<input type="checkbox" class ="" id="correct" name="correct[][correct]"/>
<button class="" id = "btn_add"> Add</button>
</form_answer>
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btn_add').click(function(){
            add_row();
        });
    });

    function add_row(){
        var id = $("#row").val();
        id++;
        var html =  '<div class="">  ' +
                    '<input type="hidden" class ="" id="correct_hidden" name="correct_hidden[][correct]" value="0"/> ' +
                    '<input type="checkbox" class ="" id="correct" name="correct[][correct]"/>' +
                    '</div>' ;
        $("form_answer").append(html);
        $("#row").val(id);
    } 


$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#correct").click(function () {
        if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
            $("#correct_hidden").val("1");
        }else{
            $("#correct_hidden").val("0");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

The script above only works on the default checkbox only. I need the script to work on all the new append checkbox. How can I solve this?

Comment: One issue is that all checkboxes have the same id - correct. You would have to make each checkbox have a different id. Then, since all other checkboxes are added dynamically, the initial click handler will not be attached to them. Like Ivan said, you need to use 'on'.

Comment: You means instead of using .click, I should use .on?

Comment: For one thing. The idea with using 'on' is that you can add a listener for elements which haven't been created yet. Then you should consider making the checkbox id's unique.

Comment: Should I use the increment number for the id ? Like $i?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the previous value `id` as local variable like below.

```js
var id = 0;
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btn_add').click(function(){
            add_row();
        });
});

function add_row(){
    id++;
    var html =  '<div class="">  ' +
                '<input type="hidden" class ="" id="correct_hidden" name="correct_hidden[][correct]" value="0"/> ' +
                '<input type="checkbox" class ="" id='+ id +' name="correct[][correct]"/>' +
                '</div>' ;
    $("form_answer").append(html);
    console.log("Id value: " + id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form_answer>
<input type="hidden" class ="" id="correct_hidden" name="correct_hidden[][correct]" value="0"/>           
<input type="checkbox" class ="" id="0" name="correct[][correct]"/>
<button class="" id = "btn_add"> Add</button>
</form_answer>
```

Comment: This is great, but the problem is the value is not change from 0 to 1 when checked the check box. The id is already incremented.

Answer (score 1):

Id's should be unique in Html. So change this to a class. Also you are adding new elements to the DOM. So you should add a eventlistener on the document and not on the element itself.

Drop the id and place it in class:

```
<input type="checkbox" class ="correct" id="" name="correct[][correct]"/>
```

Then change your js so it doesn't add id's

```
var html =  '<div class="">  ' +
                    '<input type="hidden" class ="correct_hidden" id="" name="correct_hidden[][correct]" value="0"/> ' +
                    '<input type="checkbox" class ="correct" id="" name="correct[][correct]"/>' +
                    '</div>' ;
```

At last change the eventlistener to document and trigger it on  this class

```
$(document).on('click', '.correct', function () {
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
        $("#correct_hidden").val("1");
    }else{
        $("#correct_hidden").val("0");
    }
});
```

Comment: Understood, but the id still not unique even I change from using id to class. Right?

Comment: You got the remove the id. To select the checkboxes still the easy way, give them a class. (You don't need an id actually)

Comment: I made an edit. The class won't be unique no, but is that a problem?

Comment: I can't touch the class area because it is customized. I manage to make the id increment and all, it just the jquery did not work on the append checkbox. I plan to make the jquery in loop but have no idea how to do so.

Comment: Instead of using class, it is just the same if I use type like 'input[type=checkbox]' right?

Comment: it works, but only if I checked all checkboxes. if one checkbox unchecked, all return 0 same goes to if all checked, all return 1